# Set latex-preview-pane-mode as default pdf-viewer for acutex

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

Basically, i want my emacs to run `latex-preview-pane-mode` (which is a emacs function, provided by [this package](https://github.com/jsinglet/latex-preview-pane)) instead of executing the external application `evince`.

After reading [the acutex docs about this](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Viewing), i have now this code:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(TeX-view-program-list
   (quote
    (("preview-pane-mode"
      (latex-preview-pane-mode)
      nil))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection
   (quote
    (((output-dvi has-no-display-manager)
      "dvi2tty")
     ((output-dvi style-pstricks)
      "dvips and gv")
     (output-dvi "xdvi")
     (engine-omega "Atril")
     (output-pdf "Evince")
     (output-html "xdg-open")))))
(custom-set-faces))
```

The part after `'(TeX-view-program-selection` works fine, it's the not-changed default. However, i don't know how to proceed, because obviously `evince` is a actual binary program and `latex-preview-pane-mode` a function.

After changing `(output-pdf "Evince")` to `(output-pdf 'latex-preview-pane-mode)`, i receive the error message:

```
TeX-view-command-raw: Unknown latex-preview-pane-mode viewer. Check the
`TeX-view-program-selection' variable
```

When i change it to `(output-pdf "preview-pane-mode")` and execute it, my emacs is hanging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docstring of `TeX-view-program-list`:

> The second element can be a command line to be run as a process or a Lisp function to be executed.

So you have to specify the name of the function (`latex-preview-pane-mode`), not a function call (`(latex-preview-pane-mode)`).  This is the specification for `"preview-pane-mode"` you have to use:

```lisp
("preview-pane-mode"
    latex-preview-pane-mode)
```

To avoid confusion, the full code you can add to your init file to add this entry to `TeX-view-program-list` is

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list
    'TeX-view-program-list
    '("preview-pane-mode"
      latex-preview-pane-mode)))
```

Then in `TeX-view-program-selection` pick up `"preview-pane-mode"`, not `'latex-preview-pane-mode`.

Comment: A malformed value of `TeX-view-program-list' shouldn't hang Emacs anymore: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=d418e9a064e4158556dacb33744d610097eff04b

Comment: I had to use `(("preview-pane-mode" latex-preview-pane-mode))`. With single Braces I receive the error `mapc: Wrong type argument: listp, "preview-pane-mode"`..

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, that wasn't the whole value of `TeX-view-program-list` but the specification for `preview-pane-mode`.  I'll update the answer